# Extending Square loyalty program

Tags: square-connect

While "buy 10 get 1 free" style of the loyalty program is very basic it's still useful and we're trying to remain the boundaries of Square and avoid another software. We're trying to promote customer referencing and issue a start for every referred customer.

I was thinking to develop a simple "invite friends" page where our existing customers could add emails/phones of their friends and send an invite email or text (with their phone number encoded in the unique URL). When an invited clicks on it and enter her own phone/email I want to run a script and do two things:
- register a customer to Square;
- add a "star" to the referencing person for activation. This can be implemented as purchasing a $0.01 proxy item.

Is it a stretch? Are the other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't currently a way to do what you want with the API.